# How can I sort through a forgotten password to attempt to brute force it

Tags: c#, algorithm, brute-force

so, I wanted to configure my router, it's a crappy no-name one, so there is no way to connect to a console port.
The only way would be through the browser.
No I have configured a password before and I even wrote it down. Turns out, i probably wrote it wrongly, so yeah...

I tried every combination and still no success. Since I don't want to reset the router, because of reasons, except if I really have to, I decided to write a small program to try every possibility.
Of course I can't be bothered to actually brute-force it, since the password I chose was quite strong.
So instead, I decided to make this program write a dictionary based on the password that I wrote down. This would mean, change 'a' for 'A' or '@' and so on.

I wrote a small concept code but really got stuck on the recursion part, where the passwords are actually saved on to the file.

So I am asking if anybody can share some kind fo algorith that would facilitate this.

My approach is as follows:

-Create a List of char arrays
-for every character of the input, create an array with multiple possibilities for that character.
(so say the character is an 'a', create a char array with all the possibilities mentioned above and save this char array to the list
-iterate over all possibilities and save each on onto the txt file

-use hydra or similar to brute force the router.

would be very grateful for help, take care guys

take care guys

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;

    namespace strGen
{
    class Program
    {
        static List<char[]> ls { get; set; }
        static string Path { get; set; }
        static string input { get; set; }
        static char[] inputChars { get; set; }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter tip: ");
            input = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter path: ");
            Path = Console.ReadLine();

            inputChars = input.ToCharArray();
            MakeList(inputChars);


        }

        /// <summary>
        /// makes list of all possible characters, for every character in a character array
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="inputChars"></param>
        static void MakeList(char[] inputChars)
        {

            ls = new List<char[]>();

            foreach (char c in inputChars)
            {
                char cU;
                char cL;
                char[] tmp;
                if (char.IsLetter(c))
                {
                    if (c == 'a' | c == 'A')
                    {
                        tmp = new char[3];
                        if (char.IsUpper(c))
                        {
                            cL = char.ToLower(c);
                            cU = c;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cL = c;
                            cU = char.ToUpper(c);
                        }
                        tmp[0] = cL;
                        tmp[1] = cU;
                        tmp[2] = '@';

                    }
                    else if (c == 's' | c == 'S')
                    {
                        tmp = new char[3];
                        if (char.IsUpper(c))
                        {
                            cL = char.ToLower(c);
                            cU = c;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cL = c;
                            cU = char.ToUpper(c);
                        }
                        tmp[0] = cL;
                        tmp[1] = cU;
                        tmp[2] = '5';

                    }

                    else
                    {
                        tmp = new char[2];


                        if (char.IsUpper(c))
                        {
                            cL = char.ToLower(c);
                            cU = c;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cL = c;
                            cU = char.ToUpper(c);
                        }
                        tmp[0] = cL;
                        tmp[1] = cU;
                    }

                }
                else if (char.IsDigit(c))
                {
                    if (c == '1')
                    {
                        tmp = new char[2];
                        tmp[0] = c;
                        tmp[1] = '!';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tmp = new char[1];
                        tmp[0] = c;

                    }
                }
                else if (c == '!')
                {
                    tmp = new char[2];
                    tmp[0] = c;
                    tmp[1] = '1';
                }
                else
                {
                    tmp = new char[1];
                    tmp[0] = c;
                }

                ls.Add(tmp);
            }
        }
        static void Append(string str)
        {
            File.AppendAllText(Path, str + "\\r \\n");          
        }

        static void Calc(string str, int index)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i<ls[index].Length;i++)
            {
                if (index < ls.Count)
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: resetting the router is the best way, Brute force and all might not work everywhere, what if there is a TIme delay for such attacks.

Comment: I didn't have to. Turns out there was no timeout or anything. Cracked it in about 10 minutes. I alerted my SP to this and they told me I would have to pay extra for a hardware upgrade, since this was the free router that came with the internet package. So I ended up just buying a Cisco 871 of ebay. What a beauty!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The program is rather simple

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Console.Write("Enter tip: ");
    //string input = Console.ReadLine();
    //Console.Write("Enter path: ");
    //string path = Console.ReadLine();

    string input = "A52";
    string path = "tst.txt";

    CalcAndSave(input, path);
}

static void CalcAndSave(string str, string path)
{
    List<char[]> ls = MakeList(str);
    char[] state = new char[ls.Count];

    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(path))
    {
        CalcAndSave(ls, 0, state, writer);
    }
}

static void CalcAndSave(List<char[]> ls, int level, char[] state, StreamWriter writer)
{
    if (level >= ls.Count)
    {
        foreach (char c in state)
        {
            writer.Write(c);
        }
        writer.Write("\r\n");
        return;
    }

    foreach (char c in ls[level])
    {
        state[level] = c;
        CalcAndSave(ls, level + 1, state, writer);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// makes list of all possible characters, for every character in a character array
/// </summary>
/// <param name="inputChars"></param>
static List<char[]> MakeList(string input)
{
    var same = new List<string> { "a@&", "s5", "1!" };

    var ls = new List<char[]>();

    foreach (char c in input)
    {
        HashSet<char> chars = new HashSet<char>
        {
            char.ToLower(c),
            char.ToUpper(c)
        };

        foreach (char cs in same
            .Where(s => s.Contains(c, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            .SelectMany(s => s))
        {
            chars.Add(char.ToLower(cs));
            chars.Add(char.ToUpper(cs));
        }

        ls.Add(chars.ToArray());
    }

    return ls;     
}
```

While you can use static variables, I removed them. It makes program easier to follow, as you separate the parts. There are some things to notice

- string itself is an `IEnumerable`, so you can loop through it
- it is often convenient to have two fuctions for recursion. One does the actual recursion and one provides simple interface and starts the recursion
- recursive function has two parts. Terminating condition and recursive step. Level increases on every step.

This is probably what you needed. But I would like to add something more. What you are trying to do is iterating over n-dimensional space. The most straightforward option is using some form of vector iterator - an array of scalar iterators. Recursion does that, it uses stack with scalar iterator on every level. It creates scalar iterators when going to deeper levels and destroys the finished iterators when going up. But it is not the only option. In the end, every recursion can be transformed into non recursion program. What you really need is some memory, that can hold n iterators. Then you just advance this memory in every step.